# Autotools copy data files to staging area

Tags: autotools, staging

So I've been working with Autotools trying to learn the toolchain so I can use it in some of my cross-platform projects. I've got a pretty good handle on the very basics, but I've run into an issue here.

In my source tree I have a "data" folder that contains a sub-directory with XML files and another sub-directory with image files.

i.e.:

```
data\
    cars\
    images
```

I want to be able to copy these files into the staging area using the same directory structure.

I've tried creating a Makefile.am in data and then doing something like:

```
data_DATA = cars/file1.xml cars/file2.xml images/image1.png images/image2.png
```

etc...

This "almost" works. It copies all of the files into the "share" folder in the staging area, but the underlying directory structure is lost; all of the files are in the 'share' root.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

---

**Edit:**

Ahh I seem to have figured it out (I think.)

```
data_carsdir = $(prefix)/data/cars
data_cars_DATA =  cars/file1.xml cars/file2.xml

data_imagesdir = $(prefix)/data/images
data_images_DATA =  images/image1.png images/image1.png
```

This seems to work the way I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is:

```
nobase_data_DATA = cars/file1.xml cars/file2.xml \
                   images/image1.png images/image2.png
```